# How to use pluck to get specific data from other table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

From `SalesController`, I want to get specific `name` from table `Item` and passed to HTML.

My controller looks like

```
public function index()
{
    $items=Item::orderBy('name','ASC')->get()->pluck('name','id');
    $sales=Sale::all();
    return view('Sale.index')->with('sales',$sales,'items',$items);
}
```

My HTML is

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($sales as $sale)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $sale->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $sale->items->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $sale->quantity }}</td>
            <td>RM {{ $sale->price }}</td>
            <td>{{ $sale->created_at }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But I get the following error after trying to access the page:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventoryApp\resources\views\Sale\index.blade.php)

Comment: what is relation between sales and items ?

Comment: your concept is not clear. do you have relationship between sale and item?? if so you need not to fetch item collection at all. share your model code

Comment: I removed the phpMyAdmin tag because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two way

**1.Using relationship**

```
class Sale extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id','id');
    }

}
```

so you can use like below

```
<td>{{ $sale->item->name }}</td>
```

**2. Using array data**

```
public function index()
{
     $items=Item::orderBy('name','ASC')->pluck('name','id')->toArray();
     $sales=Sale::all();
     return view('Sale.index')->with('sales',$sales,'items',$items);
 }



<td>{{ $items[$sale->item_id] }}</td>
```

Comment: u haven't used with('item')

Comment: @phpdroid without using with(), we can call relationship in view

Comment: then whats the use of sending `$items` array separately to view?

Comment: i have mention two ways please check my answer

Comment: I try using the relationship and it's working. Thank you. Does it mean that I do not need to declare the foreign key in sale the table:  `$table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: not must. but defining foreign key like this is good practice

Answer (score 0):

```
$items=Item::orderBy('name','ASC')->pluck('name','id');
```

and use `$items` directly without `sale` object

Answer (score 0):

If you have relationship with table Sale.

Add this function to your Sale Class.

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

In your controller you can use compact

```
public function index()
{
    $items=Item::orderBy('name','ASC')->get();
    $sales=Sale::all();
    return view('Sale.index')->compact('sales','items');
}
```

And you can use Eager load to your HTML.

```
<tbody>
            @foreach($sales as $sale)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $sale->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->item->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->quantity }}</td>
                    <td>RM {{ $sale->price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->created_at }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to get a property of item name that does not exist on the sale object. you can simply do it by eloquent relationship as follows:
On your sale model:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id');
}
```

On your controller:

```
public function index()
{
     $sales=Sale::all();
     return view('Sale.index',compact('sales'));
}
```

Then on your blade you can easily get related Item name:

```
@foreach($sales as $sale)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $sale->item->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```